# Invoke a method in Singleton class using reflection in java

Tags: java, android, reflection, singleton

I have a following class:

```
Public class ABCinfo { 
    private static ABCinfo instance = null;
    Public static ABCinfo getInstance(Param param); // get instance
    Private ABCinfo(Param); // making a Singleton class
    Public void methodA(Param1 param1); // need to invoke this method
}
```

using reflection in java, how can i invoke the `methodA()`.
Basically I am writing an Android Application, i want to use method in already existing(assume it will be present all the time) application which is in the phone.

Below are the things I have tried:

```
String apkName = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).sourceDir;

PathClassLoader myPathClassLoader =
    new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(
    apkName,
    ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());

Class<?> handler = Class.forName(className, true, myPathClassLoader);
Method m0 = handler.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance", new Class[] { Param.class  });
m0.setAccessible(true);
Object b = m0.invoke(null, new Object[]{ Param});
Method m = handler.getMethod("methodA", new Class[] { Param1.class});
Param1 methodParameter = "asdf";
Object b1 = m.invoke(b, new Object[] { methodParameter });
```

But its still not working.

Comment: You cannot access `Class`es that are part of another Android application. Consider making the aforementioned class a `Service` and communicating via `Intent`s.

Comment: Exactly not an application, but a framework!! The methods are accessible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and its like below

```
Object b1 = m.invoke(handler.newInstance(), new Object[] { methodParameter });
```

Comment: How were you able to invoke newInstance on handler which is of ABCinfo type ? The constructor for ABCinfo is private and you cannot instantiate this class. Your solution will not and did not work, unless you made some other changes in ABCinfo.

Comment: Your actual code with passing "b" instead of handler.newInstance() worked for me.